ChangeNotifierProvider no funciona
Necesito ayuda. Estuve viendo unos video tutoriales como para poder refrescar una lista de Card's en Flutter, pero no funciona.
La idea es utilizar Provider, Consumer y esas cosas, pero me tira un error. En internet no encuentro la explicación precisa de qué pueda estar sucediendo.
Cuando ejecuto el Provider.of(context, listen: false).shouldRefresh(); me salta un error más grande que una casa, y el IDE de Android no es muy amigable que digamos.
La idea es que refresque este Widget.
import 'package:date_time_picker/date_time_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:haytabla_flutter/db/database.dart';
import 'package:haytabla_flutter/model/alumno.dart';
import 'package:haytabla_flutter/db/database.dart';
import 'package:haytabla_flutter/model/alumno.dart';
import 'package:haytabla_flutter/notifier.dart';
import 'package:haytabla_flutter/widget/card_alumno.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Alumnos extends StatefulWidget {
  const Alumnos({super.key});

  @override
  State<Alumnos> createState() => _AlumnosState();
}

class _AlumnosState extends State<Alumnos> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Key id = GlobalKey<State<StatefulWidget>>();

    return ChangeNotifierProvider<AlumnoNotifier>(
        create: (context) => AlumnoNotifier(),
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                title: const Text(
                  'Alumnos',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            const SnackBar(content: Text('Información')));
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.person_search),
                      tooltip: 'Muestra popup'),
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            const SnackBar(content: Text('Información')));
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.sort),
                      tooltip: 'Muestra popup')
                ]),
            body: Consumer<AlumnoNotifier>(builder: (context, value, child) {
              return FutureBuilder(
                  future: HayTablaDatabase.getAllAlumnos(),
                  builder: (context,
                      AsyncSnapshot<List<Alumno>> snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      List<Alumno> alumnos = snapshot.data!;

                      return alumnos.isEmpty
                          ? const Center(
                              child: Text("No hay alumnos registrados."))
                          : ListView.builder(
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                return CardAlumno(alumnos[index]);
                              },
                              itemCount: alumnos.length);
                    } else {
                      return const Center(
                          child: Text("No hay alumnos registrados."));
                    }
                  });
            }),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
              tooltip: 'Agregar estudiante',
              onPressed: () {
                AniadirEstudiante(context);
              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white, size: 28),
            )));
  }
}

Future AniadirEstudiante(BuildContext context) {
  var fechanacimiento = TextEditingController();
  var nombres = TextEditingController();
  var apellidos = TextEditingController();
  var dni = TextEditingController();
  var correoelectronico = TextEditingController();
  var telefono = TextEditingController();
  DateTime? dateTime;
  return showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
      scrollable: true,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))),
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      title: Text(
        'Añadir estudiante',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
      content: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Nombres'),
              controller: nombres),
          TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Apellidos'),
              controller: apellidos),
          TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'D.N.I.'),
              controller: dni),
          TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Fecha de Nacimiento'),
              readOnly: true,
              autofocus: false,
              controller: fechanacimiento,
              onTap: () async {
                dateTime = await showDatePicker(
                    context: context,
                    firstDate: DateTime(2000),
                    lastDate: DateTime(2030));
                if (dateTime != null) {
                  fechanacimiento.text =
                      DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(dateTime!);
                }
              }),
          TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Correo electrónico'),
              controller: correoelectronico),
          TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Teléfono'),
              controller: telefono)
        ],
      ),
      actions: [
        TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: Text('Cancelar')),
        TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              HayTablaDatabase.insert(Alumno(
                  nombres: nombres.text,
                  apellidos: apellidos.text,
                  fechaNacimiento: dateTime!,
                  dni: dni.text,
                  telefono: telefono.text,
                  correoElectronico: correoelectronico.text));
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                  content: Text('El alumno ha sido registrado.')));
              Provider.of<AlumnoNotifier>(context, listen: false)
                  .shouldRefresh();
            },
            child: Text('Guardar'))
      ],
    ),
  );
}

desde esta otra clase..
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:haytabla_flutter/db/database.dart';
import 'package:haytabla_flutter/model/alumno.dart';
import 'package:haytabla_flutter/notifier.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class CardAlumno extends StatelessWidget {
  final Alumno cardAlumnoItem;

  const CardAlumno(this.cardAlumnoItem);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 380,
      height: 70,
      child: Card(
        color: Colors.white12,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            CircleAvatar(
              child: Text(
                  '${cardAlumnoItem.apellidos[0]}${cardAlumnoItem.nombres[0]}'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
              foregroundColor: Colors.white,
              radius: 23,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 8,
            ),
            Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text('${cardAlumnoItem.apellidos}, ${cardAlumnoItem.nombres}',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white)),
                  Text(
                    '${cardAlumnoItem.dni}',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                  )
                ]),
            const Spacer(),
            IconButton(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              highlightColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
              color: Colors.deepPurple,
            ),
            IconButton(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                highlightColor: Colors.white,
                onPressed: () {
                  showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) {
                        return AlertDialog(
                          title: const Text('Alert Dialog Title'),
                          content: const Text(
                              'This is the content of the alert dialog.'),
                          actions: <Widget>[
                            TextButton(
                              child: const Text('Cancel'),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                            ),
                            TextButton(
                              child: const Text('Confirm'),
                              onPressed: () async {
                                Navigator.pop(context);
                                await HayTablaDatabase.delete(
                                    cardAlumnoItem.id_alumno!);
                                Provider.of<AlumnoNotifier>(context,
                                        listen: false)
                                    .shouldRefresh();
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      });
                },
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.delete,
                  color: Colors.deepPurple,
                ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Código del Provider
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AlumnoNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  void shouldRefresh(){
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

Si alguien me pudiera indicar el error, se lo agradecería.
Refrescar la lista de alumnos.

Quizás se bueno que agregues el código del provider para una mejor respuesta. Como adelanto te digo que no parece que utilices el value del Consumer, entonces no utilizas el provider por lo tanto.

Ahí añadí el código del Provider, no hace mucho, solo llama a la función  notifyListeners();

ok, en realidad solo manda hacer el rebuild(redibujar los widgets contenidos debajo del Consumer. Para empezar no todo esta mal pero si la idea de para que usar el Provider. Voy a proponerte algo como respuesta y lo vamos mejorando segun avances. Pero lo primero es mover las operaciones para el provider y usar el provider. Detalle, te estoy pasando todo a una Lista local para hacerlo mas entendible.

class AlumnoNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  final _isLoading = false;
  List<Alumnos> _listAlumnos = [];

  bool get isLoading => _isLoading;
  List<Alumnos> get alumnos => _listAlumnos;

  // Insertar
  void insert(Alumno alumno) {
    // Muestra Loading (necesario para cuando tu operacion sea async)
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    _listAlumnos.add(alumno);
    // HayTablaDatabase.insert(alumno);
    _isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

El provider contiene los eventos y como responder a eso.
class Alumnos extends StatefulWidget {
  const Alumnos({super.key});

  @override
  State<Alumnos> createState() => _AlumnosState();
}

class _AlumnosState extends State<Alumnos> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return ChangeNotifierProvider<AlumnoNotifier>(
        create: (context) => AlumnoNotifier(),
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                title: const Text(
                  'Alumnos',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            const SnackBar(content: Text('Información')));
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.person_search),
                      tooltip: 'Muestra popup'),
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            const SnackBar(content: Text('Información')));
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.sort),
                      tooltip: 'Muestra popup')
                ]),
            body: Consumer<AlumnoNotifier>(builder: (context, value, child) {
              final alumnos = value._listAlumnos;
              return alumnos.isEmpty
                  ? const Center(child: Text("No hay alumnos registrados."))
                  : ListView.builder(
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return CardAlumno(alumnos[index]);
                      },
                      itemCount: alumnos.length);
            }),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
              tooltip: 'Agregar estudiante',
              onPressed: () {
                aniadirEstudiante(context);
              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white, size: 28),
            )));
  }
}

Ahora en la pagina usariamos solamente el Provider para obtener datos (por eso se quita el FutureBuilder). Nota, el ChangeNotifierProvider deberias ponerlo más arriba en tu app. Al menos por ahora hasta que te funcione y veas la lógica.
Espero te sirvan los cambios mas que nada a entender que la lógica la quitamos hacia el provider y como se "conecta" con la UI.Suerte!
